# How to darken toolbar from fragment on Android

Tags: android, material-design

What I really want to do is darken the `toolbar` when I open another `fragment`, but in the same way that happens when `navigation drawer` is open. Something like this:

[image: darken toolbar]

Comment: Material Design guidelines say that Navigation Drawer must go over the toolbar and under the status bar. Just like e.g. Play Store and Play Music

Comment: @BamsBamx ok, but that wasn't my question. This is just a gif i found on [GitHub](https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template) that describes my situation.

Comment: The shadow cast is the scrim color of the navigation drawer.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski thanks, but how do I apply it to `toolbar` only?

Comment: @head01 Set scrim color to Color.TRANSPARENT, use drawer slide offset to increment toolbar background alpha.